# NodeJS + Android, Socket.io chat , app crashes on user leaving the chat room

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am using Socket.IO for a chat app I am making. I am a beginner with both node.js and android.

The chat actually works, but when a person leaves a chat room, any chat room, the app crashes and I have to restart it for another user/users to be able to chat again.

The error I get is the following:

> C:\Users\Tasos\Desktop\node.js
>   server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\ultron\index.js:80
>         if (this.ee._events.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
>                             ^
>
> TypeError: this.ee._events.hasOwnProperty is not a function
>       at Ultron.remove (C:\Users\Tasos\Desktop\node.js server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\ultron\index.js:80:27)
>       at Ultron.destroy (C:\Users\Tasos\Desktop\node.js server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\ultron\index.js:116:8)
>       at WebSocket.cleanupWebsocketResources (C:\Users\Tasos\Desktop\node.js
>   server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:851:36)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Any hints as to what could be at fault here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged with `android`

Comment: @Ryan you are right, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that socket.io is the latest version?

Comment: @Ryan holy shit this is it. How did you know? Create an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: It's the first thing I check when something isn't working and the stack trace isn't my code :)

Comment: @Ryan I will keep it in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the socket.io version is the latest

`npm install socket.io --save`

Comment: no help for me . This is log : node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/ultron/index.js:80
if (this.ee._events.hasOwnProperty(event)) {TypeError: this.ee._events.hasOwnProperty is not a function